# Ideas for a good but easy to use game engine for an XNA project

Tags: xna, game-engine

I have been looking around and the best engine I can find is this: http://unigine.com/
The problem is a full licence starts around £18,000 which i just cant afford in the real world.

So ...

I'm looking to do something unique in my project that involves dynamic terrain that can be moved in realtime whilst the user is in game and "stood" on it, other than that it's pretty much the same as any other WOW clone out there.

I'm also looking for something that (if i decide later to consider this a serious career option) would be taken serious by the industry as a real skill set to have.

Any ideas?

-- EDIT --
I am already an experienced developer but I build line of business applications for pushing data around between companies and departments so I don't need guides / tutorials as such.

I have also done a bit of XNA myself (tried building my own engine) but decided to use a prebult engine to reduce my project lifecycle.

Comment: You might want to search gamedev.stackexchange.com -- lots of good content on there.

Comment: thanks nate :) il give that a try ... im so disappointed i can't have a play with unigine though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vanquish](http://project-vanquish.co.cc) is what we are currently working on, but [QuickStartEngine](http://quickstartengine.codeplex.com/) has a lot features including terrain.

Comment: Thanks Ardman :) ... From digging around and asking a few friends I found that the Quick start engine seems to be a common favourite ... im gonna give it a try and see how I get on.

Comment: Please keep Vanquish in mind as we are making improvements all of the time. For example, we have had a SkyDome and also video playback to RenderTargets. ;-)

Comment: @Wardy: Yes I am.  Are you interested in it?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about SunBurn see: http://www.synapsegaming.com/products/sunburn/engine/

The pricing starts at $150,- which seems very affordable

Comment: I like this but it didn't come across as being a serious engine for serious hardware ... is this for the new WP7 platform by any chance? ... I'm looking for somehting to build the next big MMORPG on.

Comment: Seriously if you can't even afford $18.000,- for the UNIENGINE, then you're in no shape to build "The next big MMORPG", why not start nice and small?